# How to grab right-hand side results from Bing using Bing's API

Tags: bing, bing-api

When you use Bing or Google, searching for certain types of things will give you a special information box on the side that grabs info from top hits, usually Wikipedia.
[image: Example]
Is there any way to ask for this box using Bing's API? I suppose you can ask for the whole page and then try to piece it out, but I'd rather just get this entire box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm from the Bing API team. There is a Bing API to get information about entities (the right rail box you mention), known as Knowledge and Action Graph API: https://www.bing.com/partners/knowledgegraph. Unfortunately, this is currently a private API, which is not offered broadly yet.

Comment: Cool! I noticed that the sign-up page seems very focused to actual business entities. Is there any avenue for a college team hoping to use the advanced API's for a school project to get access?

Comment: Unfortunately not at the moment.

Comment: Any updates? The entity search api does not return the same results e.g. if I query "apollo tyre 4g life 165/65", the right side box returns nice structured information and entity/bing search api returns just web pages.